# How to say that an incapability would have been shared by others

Tags: grammar, expression-choice

I'm a non-native speaker struggling with a construct that should emphasize that someone's incapability would have been shared by others.

Picture a man with a stone in his shoe. He walks on and on but then the pain gets too much.

> He couldn’t bear it any more, no `one could have` / `could have had`

Which of the two is correct? Are there alternatives?

Comment: The correct one if you had to use that construct is the first one: "no one could have." there's an understanding that what you're actually saying is "He couldn't bear it any( )more, no one could have (bore it any more)" but because you're repeating the verb phrase from the first clause, it's implied in the second and can be left out.

Comment: @JohnClifford Thanks. You say "if you had to use". Does that mean it is awkward in any way?

Comment: Speaking of that, it depends on context. Have had has a relation to current time, which implies the pain still goes on. Since this construct is usually used with finished, past events, I'm with John on this. Almost forgot to mention that couldn't bear is a finished action - or so i think. There are plenty of alternatives/variants/rephrasings that could be used as well - that's what John was trying to imply with "if you had to use", I think.

Comment: The only awkward thing is that because it's technically an independent clause (if you include the omitted verb phrase) and is closely-related to the clause preceding it, I would have used a semicolon. But it's possible that I'm wrong about it being independent, so maybe it's fine as-is. And yeah, there are other ways to express the same sentiment as Sakatox said.